# Unable to Change vCenter Server Appliance IP

Tags: vmware-vcenter

I am trying to change a vCenter Server Appliance static IP address.

If I follow VMware documentation [here](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-60/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.vcsa.doc%2FGUID-56C3BA9A-234E-4D81-A4BC-E2A37892A854.html) I get the following message

```
IPv4 configuration for nic0 of this node cannot be edited post deployment.
```

Logging in through console doesn't allow me to change the address.

Editing `/etc/sysconfig/networking/devices/ifcfg-eth0` will cause permission issues.

Executing `/opt/vmware/share/vami/vami_config_net` in shell gives the error `ImportError: No module named libxml2mod`

I have tried to install libxml2mod with Zypper but can't find this specific package and already have libxml installed.

How can I change my IP address?

vCSA is version 6 build 2562643

Comment: Please provide versions and build numbers.

Comment: Apologies, have added.

Comment: What's with the down vote? I could of sworn this was the place to ask questions you couldn't find the answer to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds as though you may have used an IP address rather than a FQDN for the vCenter name during installation.  If that is indeed the case, you may be out of luck:

> Prerequisites
>
> To change the IP settings of the vCenter Server
>   Appliance, make sure that the system name of the appliance is an FQDN.
>   If, during the vCenter Server Appliance deployment, you set up the
>   appliance to use an IP address as a system name, you cannot change the
>   IP settings.

(From: [Configuring the vCenter Server Appliance by Using the Direct Console User Interface](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-60/index.jsp#com.vmware.vsphere.vcsa.doc/GUID-0B9988FF-5FB6-4656-9C58-EE3617B57E90.html) )

Comment: I just wanted to add . . . if this is in fact the case, you might as well bite the bullet now and reinstall vCenter.  You *might* be able to circumvent VMware's protections against changing the IP, but you'll forever be running into troubles where the original IP was written into various obscure configuration files. (whereas with a FQDN, you'd just update DNS)

Comment: Thanks for this, you're right, I did use an IP address. VMware documentation is awful- unless I'm missing something, the link I posted in the question doesn't mention that.

Comment: You're not missing anything (this fact is not mentioned in THAT section) and the documentation is awful.  IMHO, VMware should STRESS this limitation in all the documentation referring to the system name, including the ramifications of using an IP rather than a FQDN (not just " , , , a FQDN is recommended . . .")

Comment: (and reverse DNS is helpful, too)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't feel like redeploying vCenter Server Appliance, so I took a risk and edited the raw linux networking config.  Not the approved solution, but it seems to be working fine.  If it stops working, then I'm right back where I started (needing to redeploy).

Go to the appliance management page and enable the SSH login and Bash shell:

```
https://static-ip-address:5480
```

[image]

Then ssh to the appliance.  Login as root, and the default password is `vmware`. If you set a password for the appliance for the web client, then use that password with the root username.

```
Connected to service

    * List APIs: "help api list"
    * List Plugins: "help pi list"
    * Enable BASH access: "shell.set --enabled True"
    * Launch BASH: "shell"

Command>
```

Launch the shell by typing the command "shell"

```
shell
```

edit the interfaces config in linux

```
 vim /etc/sysconfig/networking/devices/ifcfg-eth0
```

and you should see something like this

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO='static'
STARTMODE='auto'
TYPE=Ethernet
USERCONTROL='no'
IPADDR='10.8.3.11'
NETMASK='255.255.255.0'
BROADCAST='10.8.3.255'
```

Make the changes you want, then restart the networking service.

```
localhost:~ # service network restart
Shutting down network interfaces:
    eth0      device: VMware VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller                    done
Shutting down service network  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .                    done
Hint: you may set mandatory devices in /etc/sysconfig/network/config
Setting up network interfaces:
    eth0      device: VMware VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller
    eth0      IP address: 10.8.3.11/21                                      done
Setting up service network  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .                    done
```